# How to setup Elixir project to use RabbitMQ via amqp?

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, phoenix-framework, elixir

I want to use rabbitMQ from my elixir phoenix app via amqp. I followed tutorial on [official website](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-elixir.html) but still during `mix.deps compile`, I get an error:

```
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:30: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:31: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:32: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:34: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:35: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:36: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:37: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:38: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:39: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:42: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:30: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:31: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:32: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:34: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:35: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:36: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:37: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:38: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:39: syntax error before: '/'
include/amqp_gen_consumer_spec.hrl:42: syntax error before: '/'
Compiling src/amqp_selective_consumer.erl failed:
ERROR: compile failed while processing /home/bmarkons/soc2016-marko/telegram/deps/amqp_client: rebar_abort
** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :amqp_client, "/usr/bin/rebar compile skip_deps=true deps_dir="/home/bmarkons/soc2016-marko/telegram/_build/dev/lib"" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile amqp_client", update it with "mix deps.update amqp_client" or clean it with "mix deps.clean amqp_client"
```

[Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBW8P.png)

I added only :amqp and {:amqp, "~> 0.1.4"}, in mix.exs file:

```
def application do
    [mod: {App, []},
     applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_pubsub, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                    :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :amqp]]
end

defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.0"},
     {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
     {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
     {:amqp, "~> 0.1.4"}]
end
```

What changes I need to make, to have my elixir app work with rabbitMQ?

Thank you

Comment: Well, that's odd. Have you tried to clean your dependencies? `mix deps.clean --all` and then `mix deps.get` and `mix deps.compile`. Also, which version of Elixir are you using?

Comment: I am using Elixir 1.3.1. I tried that also but still getting an error.

Comment: What's the Erlang version?

Comment: Running erl -eval 'erlang:display(erlang:system_info(otp_release)), halt().'  -noshell gives me '19'.

Comment: Yeah, I think there's a bug in Erlang 19. I have seen a similar problem before, but with other repository https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/1168. I have Erlang 18 in my machine and it can compile `:amqp` without problems, so I suggest you try that as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just got the same answer on rabbitmq-users google group. Cheers :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a reported issue in the `:amqp` project (https://github.com/pma/amqp/issues/28) It fails compilation with Erlang 19. The problem lies in `:amqp_client`. The last version in the repository is fixed, but it does not exist as a hex package yet.

**Update 2016-08-16:**

If you want to use `AMQP` with Erlang 19 in your project just add the current `:amqp_client` dependency to override the one that comes with `AMQP`:

```
def deps do
  [{:amqp_client, git: "https://github.com/jbrisbin/amqp_client.git", override: true},
   {:amqp, "~> 0.1.4"}]
end
```

For this concrete example you should have something like:

```
defp deps do
  [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.0"},
   {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
   {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
   {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
   {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
   {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
   {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
   {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
   {:amqp_client, git: "https://github.com/jbrisbin/amqp_client.git", override: true},
   {:amqp, "~> 0.1.4"]
end
```

> Important: You should override the `:amqp_client` dependency in projects that use `AMQP` event if their mix file is already overriding the dependency.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I recently updated erlang and getting this error. I followed your steps and it compiled. However, there was a small change that I had to do - I had to change {:amqp, github: "<your github username>/amqp"} to {:amqp_client, github: "<your github username>/amqp"} and :amqp in applications to :amqp_clients.

But now it is giving this error : module AMQP is not loaded and could not be found [on this line - use AMQP ]

Can you tell me what could be the reason and how to resolve this?

Comment: @KshitijMittal I updated the workaround for one that is currently working for me. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 7):

I had to define the dependency as follows (branch information) to get it to run:

```
defp deps do
[
  {:amqp_client, git: "https://github.com/dsrosario/amqp_client.git", branch: "erlang_otp_19", override: true},
  {:amqp, "~> 0.1.4"}
]
```

end